# Error 1053 when starting windows service

Tags: windows, services

I have a dummy application that I want to start as a Windows service. The application doesn't exist yet, but I know it needs to start automatically when the computer boots, so I'm trying to set up the installer now.

I have created the service with the following command:

```
sc create ServiceName binpath= C:\path\to\ServiceName.exe start= auto displayname= "Better Service Name"
```

This seems to work, I can see the service in Computer Management with the correct properties set.

However when I start the service, I see that the exe starts in the Task Manager, but then the Service Control window reports

**"Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."**

And then the exe dies.

I have tried a registry edit to extend the timeout from 30sec to 180sec but that hasn't helped.

I also tried the steps suggested [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2484025/windows-search-service-will-not-start-error-the-windows-search-service), but I wasn't able to delete any of the files, "because the file is open in System". I'm not entirely sure what that means, but I haven't been able to solve it.

Is there anything else I can do to try to make this start?

I'm also open to other options for making this exe automatically start. I like the convenience of having a service in case it crashes for any reason, it might be easier to manage, but I'm not hard-line on that.

Comment: You can't just create a service pointing at any exe.  The exe needs to be aware of the Service Control Manger and therefore needs to be written to be a service.  Maybe you can use an exe like servany - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/137890/how-to-create-a-user-defined-service to help "turn it into" a service.  It comes with the 2003 Resource Kit - https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17657